# Deleting empty nodes except some define explicit

Tags: xml, xslt

I decided to open a new topic because in  previous I did not precisly define what I'm expecting.
My XML on input looks:

```
    <tag5>
                <addresses/>
                <identifiedBaseServices/>
                <sharedGroups>
                   <names></names>
                   <types></types>
     </tag5>
     <contain>
                <attributes/>
                <addresses/>
                <identifiedBaseServices/>
                <sharedGroups>
                   <names></names>
                   <types></types>
                </sharedGroups>
     </contain>
<smth>
           <tag1></tag1>
               <tag3> TEXT </tag3>
</smth>
```

All what I want is delete empty nodes except some which I explicit define. For example I don't want to remove

```
attributes,
```

So xml OUTPUT shoud looks:

```
 <contain>
            <attributes/>
 </contain>


<smth>
           <tag3> TEXT </tag3>
</smth>
```

I was looking for some solution, after few hours i got smth like:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="attributes[not(node())]" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(.//text() | .//@*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works almost fine but only then if eg.  contain some data.When everything is null then that XSL code remove ALL empty tag...

Is anyone here who could help me? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="*[.//attributes] | attributes">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />        
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've removed your text template - it was stripping out the empty node you want to keep.  Instead, we have a template to match any node that has `attributes` as a child or the `attributes` node itself.  We then keep just that tag and ignore the rest of its children.  I don't think this will handle attributes (XML attributes that is) if you want to keep those on the `attributes` node.

Takes this document:

```
<rt>
    <tag5>
        <addresses/>
        <identifiedBaseServices/>
        <sharedGroups>
            <names/>
            <types/>
        </sharedGroups>
    </tag5>
    <contain>
        <attributes/>
        <addresses/>
        <identifiedBaseServices/>
        <sharedGroups>
            <names/>
            <types/>
        </sharedGroups>
    </contain>
    <smth>
        <tag1/>
        <tag3> TEXT </tag3>
    </smth>
</rt>
```

And produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rt>
   <contain>
      <attributes/>
   </contain>
   <smth>
      <tag3> TEXT </tag3>
   </smth>
</rt>
```

Comment: Nice xpath..., plus one.

Comment: Hi Dan, It works perfectly, but some other error now occur, when I paste your solution into my code. Could you take a look? I try to add current date into some field. And it works almost fine, but now there is also a header... I have no idea why.. http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/7  That's so weird..

Comment: What do you mean by header?  If you want to take out the `<?xml?>` declaration, you need to specify `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in the `output` node of your stylesheet...

Comment: If you open http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/7 the you see what I mean. That's so weird, Why in correlation_id tag is : <correlationId xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">.2015-09-16T17:23:53.201Zd1e8</correlationId> . Should'n be there only date + ID ?  <correlationId>.2015-09-16T17:23:53.201Zd1e8</correlationId> . But i don't want to omit header.

Comment: Try http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/8.  It's because `xsl:copy` is recognizing the possibility that there'd be something using that namespace, so it's including it.  To ignore that just create a new `correlationId` element in the empty namespace (as linked).